# unicode characters do not appear in terminal for vim airline

Tags: vim, unicode, utf-8, terminal, vim-airline

I know this has been asked a few times but none of the answers worked for me.

I use the gnome terminal as default in Ubuntu 14.10 and I can't get unicode characters to show properly, mainly in vim airline.

I have set character encoding to unicode UTF8 in the terminal menu.

and LANG returns utf8:

```
echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

I have installed a patched font from https://github.com/powerline/fonts/

I have probably also tried other tips found on stackexchange that I now can't remember and I still see the weird characters:

[image: weird characters]

When I installed the same font on OSX with iterm it worked instantly.

I have also tried in other terminals on the same system like guake or using ctrl-alt-f1 and the result is the same. I have tried inside or outside tmux as well.

Any help is welcome.